# helm reporting nil pointer evaluating interface {}.green_slot_name

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am getting a weird error.
I am running helm command inside the application helm chart and getting error as below:

```
helm upgrade --install socket-manager  -nsocket-manager .

Release "socket-manager" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: template: socket-manager/templates/service.yaml:6:37: executing "socket-manager/templates/service.yaml" at <.Values.config.green_slot_name>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.green_slot_name
```

Values.yaml is below:

```
cat Values.yaml
config:
  green_slot_name: "green"
  blue_slot_name: "blue"
```

service.yaml is below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: "{{ .Chart.Name }}"
  name: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Values.config.green_slot_name }}-{{ .Values.config.environment }}-service"
spec:
  ports:
  - port: {{ .Values.config.port }}
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: {{ .Values.config.target_port }}
  selector:
    app: "{{ .Chart.Name }}"
    slot: "{{ .Values.config.green_slot_name }}"
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: "{{ .Chart.Name }}"
  name: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Values.config.blue_slot_name }}-{{ .Values.config.environment }}-service"
spec:
  ports:
  - port: {{ .Values.config.port }}
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: {{ .Values.config.target_port }}
  selector:
    app: "{{ .Chart.Name }}"
    slot: "{{ .Values.config.blue_slot_name }}"
  type: ClusterIP
```

I wonder what is wrong here?

Comment: Seems to be working fine on https://helm-playground.com/.

Comment: Just the values file on its own isn't enough to reproduce the issue, since your template code could be doing pretty much anything.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Include the template code that causes the error directly in the question, not behind a link; delete things like the directory listing and unused values that aren't directly related to the issue.

Comment: Does the filename `Values.yaml` have an uppercase `V`?  On a system with a case-sensitive filesystem (_e.g._, native Linux) this won't be recognized, it needs a lowercase `v`.

Comment: Thanks, David! That was it. I did not know that the helm default filename should be valued.yaml with small v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, I can spot a typo in 4 occurrences in your manifests:

It should be

```
.Values.health_checks.liveliness.*
```

and not

```
.Values.health_checks.liveness.*
```

When I fixed that typo in my local it works.

You can also try to remove the double quotes from `selector` inside the service

For instance:

```
  selector:
    app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    slot: {{ .Values.config.green_slot_name }}
```

Comment: This is not an issue.